# 'define" is not defined in jquery file reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am using jQuery with React-JS. Although I am importing jQuery in my router file as shown below, it gives me a `'define' is not defined` error.

My import:

```
import './assets/js/jquery.js';
```

Comment: You shouldn't mix react with jquery. When using `create-react-app` you also get nice ES6 polyfills like `fetch()`. Consider editing your question to better reflect what you're trying to archive anyway.

Comment: `import $ from 'jquery'` - why have a local version that is not CJS aware?

Comment: i am using bootstrap and jquery with react so need to use jquery with reactjs,but couldnt find solution for this error

Comment: @ Dimitar Christoff i am using that syntax but hen i load bootstrap and popperjs to reactjs,still it shows error with popper js is undefiend ,but i installed popper.js